# compare 2 prices in jquery, if they match add a class?

Tags: jquery

How would i go about adding a class to an element in jquery, if 2 prices i return match?

Say both items (Price1 and Price2) are being returned via JSON, if they match add class="red" to an element.

Below is my existing code, I need to match **res.amzprice** and **res.lowprice**, if both match i need to add a class to the res.lowprice td :)

```
 $.ajax({ type: "POST",
    url: "aWeb.asmx/GetLowPrices",
    data: "{ }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        $('#loading').hide();
        var result = response.d;
        var new_record = "";
        $.each(result, function (index, res) {
            new_record = "<tr id=\"" + res.sku + "\">" +
                         "<td scope=\"row\" class=\"t-left\"><a href=\"../product/editproduct.aspx?sku=" + res.sku + "\" title=\"Edit this product listing\">" + res.title + "</a></td>" +
                         "<td>" + res.sku + "</td>" +
                         "<td> £" + res.tprice + "</td>" +
                         "<td class=\"amzprice-edit\"><input type=\"text\" id=\"txt" + res.sku.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '-') + "\" value=\"" + res.amzprice + "\"> <img src=\"images/icons/info.png\" alt=\"Info\" title=\"Price (inc. Shipping): £xx.xx\" /></td>" +
                         "<td> £" + res.lowprice + " <img src=\"images/icons/info.png\" alt=\"Info\" title=\"Price: £xx.xx | Shipping: £xx.xx\" /> <a href=\"lowpricedata.aspx?sku=" + res.sku + "\" id=\"lnkInfoGrpah\" class=\"link-to info-graph\" data-fancybox-type=\"iframe\"><img src=\"images/icons/graph-icon.png\" alt=\"Info\" title=\"View Lowprice History\" /></a></td>" +
                         "<td><div class=\"twe-button mini update\">Update</div></td>" +
                         "</tr>";

            $('#dataResults').append(new_record);
        });

    },
    error: function (msg) {
        $('#loading').hide();
        $('#dataTable').hide();
        $('#infoMsg').show();
        $('#infoMsg').addClass('er-red');
        $('#infoMsg').html("Error while calling web service.");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ternary Condition is what you are looking for here:

```
new_record = "<tr id=\"" + res.sku + "\">" +
                     "<td scope=\"row\" class=\"t-left\"><a href=\"../product/editproduct.aspx?sku=" + res.sku + "\" title=\"Edit this product listing\">" + res.title + "</a></td>" +
                     "<td>" + res.sku + "</td>" +
                     "<td> £" + res.tprice + "</td>" +
                     "<td class=\"amzprice-edit\"><input type=\"text\" id=\"txt" + res.sku.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '-') + "\" value=\"" + res.amzprice + "\"> <img src=\"images/icons/info.png\" alt=\"Info\" title=\"Price (inc. Shipping): £xx.xx\" /></td>" +
                     "<td class="+((res.lowprice===res.amzprice)?'red':'green')"+> £" + res.lowprice + " <img src=\"images/icons/info.png\" alt=\"Info\" title=\"Price: £xx.xx | Shipping: £xx.xx\" /> 

<a href=\"lowpricedata.aspx?sku=" + res.sku + "\" id=\"lnkInfoGrpah\" class=\"link-to info-graph\" data-fancybox-type=\"iframe\"><img src=\"images/icons/graph-icon.png\" alt=\"Info\" title=\"View Lowprice History\" /></a></td>" +
                     "<td><div class=\"twe-button mini update\">Update</div></td>" +
                     "</tr>";

        $('#dataResults').append(new_record);
```

This condition will check for price and assigns the class accordingly, it if matches gives 'red' class or 'green' class.  I have used "===" for strict check

((res.lowprice===res.amzprice)?'red':'green')

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest:

```
$.each(result, function (index, res) {

    var lowPriceClass = res.amzprice == res.lowprice ? 'red' : 'noMatch';

    new_record = "<tr id=\"" + res.sku + "\">" +
                 "<td scope=\"row\" class=\"t-left\"><a href=\"../product/editproduct.aspx?sku=" + res.sku + "\" title=\"Edit this product listing\">" + res.title + "</a></td>" +
                 "<td>" + res.sku + "</td>" +
                 "<td> £" + res.tprice + "</td>" +
                 "<td class=\"amzprice-edit\"><input type=\"text\" id=\"txt" + res.sku.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '-') + "\" value=\"" + res.amzprice + "\"> <img src=\"images/icons/info.png\" alt=\"Info\" title=\"Price (inc. Shipping): £xx.xx\" /></td>" +
                 "<td class='" + lowPriceClass + "'> £" + res.lowprice + " <img src=\"images/icons/info.png\" alt=\"Info\" title=\"Price: £xx.xx | Shipping: £xx.xx\" /> <a href=\"lowpricedata.aspx?sku=" + res.sku + "\" id=\"lnkInfoGrpah\" class=\"link-to info-graph\" data-fancybox-type=\"iframe\"><img src=\"images/icons/graph-icon.png\" alt=\"Info\" title=\"View Lowprice History\" /></a></td>" +
                 "<td><div class=\"twe-button mini update\">Update</div></td>" +
                 "</tr>";

    $('#dataResults').append(new_record);
});
```

Although it strikes me that any element showing `lowPrice` should be assessed for whether the 'low price' is *less than or equal to*, not simply *equal to*, so I'd really suggest:

```
    var lowPriceClass = res.amzprice <= res.lowprice ? 'red' : 'noMatch';
```

This approach uses a ternary operator to assess a condition to return a Boolean value, and if it's found to be true returns the first value/variable (in this case the `'red'` after the `?` and before the `:`), if it's found to be false, then it returns the second value/variable (the one *after* the `:`) and assigns that returned value/variable to the variable-name.